# st_mode not returning expected values for S_IXXX comparison

Tags: c, unix

I have a function that (ideally) would merely simulate a portion of the ls -l command. It is meant to return permissions for the file, and the name of the file. I don't really care about any other information. It also is not the cleanest, as I am stuck using the VIM editor, and it is significantly less user friendly than modern IDEs.

Code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void ls_l(const char *path){
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *file;
    struct stat fileStat;
        dir = opendir(path);
    if(!dir) {
        printf("opendir failed\n");
        return;
    }
    
    while (((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)){
        char path2[255];
        sprintf(path2, "%s/%s", path, file->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", path2);
                
        if(lstat(path2, &fileStat)) {
            printf("lstat failed\n");
            return;
        }
        //User permissions
        
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? " r" : " -");
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");  
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
            //Group permissions
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
            //Other permissions
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (fileStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x | " : "- | ");

    }
}

void doStep(int stepNum){
    chdir("dir0");
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    if(getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL){
        printf("CWD: %s\n", cwd);
    }
    else{
        printf("getcwd() error");
    }

    switch (stepNum){
        case 1:
            printf("Display files and permissions for ./dir0\n");   
            ls_l(cwd);
        break;
        
        case 2:
            printf("Change permission for file6.txt to -rwxrwx---\n");
            chmod("./file6.txt", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP |
                S_IWGRP | S_IXGRP);
        break;
        
        case 3:
            printf("Remove file1.txt and file2.txt from directory dir1\n");
        break;

        case 4:
            printf("Remove dir1 directory\n");
        break;

        case 5:
            printf("Display files and permission for ./dir0\n");

        break;
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < 2; i++){
        doStep(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am only through the user and group permissions and I already have noticed a serious problem with the code. For whatever reason, the group permissions fail to change with each file, and thus do not return the correct values. I am only aware of this because because changing the permissions of a file and checking the return with ls -l gives me different values that that of my code.

I am aware that this isn't a complete program, as I am not finished with it, but it can compile and run on my school UNIX server, so it should suffice for any testing.

I would also like to not that case 2 never functioned before I noticed this error, so if you'd like to help with that as well I would appreciate it.

Edit: I use this to compile:
'''
gcc task13prog.c -o task13prog
'''

File structure is /dir0, which contains directories /dir1 and /dir2, a regular file called file6.txt, and a symbolic link called link5. I am more or less entirely concerned with this file structure, and only this file structure.

Output as requested by Allan Wind
Slightly edited to remove username data

```
{cslinux1:~/cs3377/project2} pwd
/home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2
```

```
{cslinux1:~/cs3377/project2} ./task13prog
CWD: /home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2/dir0
Display files and permissions for ./dir0
/home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2/dir0/.
 rwx--x--x | /home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2/dir0/..
 rwx--x--x | /home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2/dir0/link5
 rwxrwxrwx | /home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2/dir0/dir2
 rwx--x--x | /home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2/dir0/file6.txt
 rwxrwxrwx | /home/013/t/tm/***/cs3377/project2/dir0/dir1
 rwx--x--x | {cslinux1:~/cs3377/project2} ls -l dir0
total 112
drwx--x--x 2 *** sn 54 Apr  3 18:38 dir1
drwx--x--x 2 *** sn 54 Apr  3 18:38 dir2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 *** sn  0 Apr  3 18:38 file6.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 *** sn 14 Apr  3 18:38 link5 -> dir2/file4.txt
{cslinux1:~/cs3377/project2}
```

Final edit:
The solution marked as correct was in fact, correct. Upon testing on a fresh linux system the solution functioned as expected. It appears that there was an error in the original environment that prevented me from making changes to permissions and reading permissions accurately.

Comment: *For whatever reason, the group permissions fail to change with each file, and thus do not return the correct values.*  And how many times do you call some version of `stat()` to ***get*** those permissions?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I knew I accidentally deleted a line while removing old code. I updated my post with an lstat function, but it still won't work. (The lstat() command was still in my code, it was just a bad copy/paste)

Comment: No point in ` lstat(".", &fileStat);`  The hard-coded directory structure makes it annoying to help you as you have to read the code then recreate the directory structure.

Comment: What does `lstat(file->d_name, &fileStat)` return? It might be -1, because the file names are relative to `dir0` but that’s not your working directory.

Comment: @AllanWind I am sorry, I didn't think that the file structure being referenced was relevant in itself. I have now provided necessary details regarding this issue. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to help you help me.

Comment: Your `~/cs3377/project2/dir0` is particular problematic.  Anyways, I think the answer below should square you away.

Comment: Your check on getcwd() is no good.  You need to check the return value not the cwd string which is always non-null.

Comment: Also need the matching ls -l output.  Also, use PATH_MAX instead of 255 (my fault).

Comment: @Allan I tried pasting ls -l output, but stackoverflow kept saying it wasnt formatted correctly. I'll try a few things to make it work, but as of now it just refuses to cooperate.

Comment: Wrap the data in the triple back quotes like you format code.

Comment: @Allan Updated as requested

Comment: ls -l and the output of your program that should give us the debug data.  Make sure you the getcwd() check.

Comment: The difference for for file6.txt where ls says "rwx--x--x" but your put says "-rwxrwxrwx" but there is nothing in your code to explain that first "-" so something is off.

Comment: @Allan The first - in the ls -l command is supposed to be that way for plain files. It is also a 'l' for link and 'd' for directory. This means that I don't have to print it in this program. I just need the permission bits.

Comment: You are right, I mixed up the two.  Remember your program changes permissions for that file.  Can you create a new file, redo your test and see if permissions match up?  The format doesn't match... like file name is printed with a trailing "\n" but it's inline in your output.  Did you recompile your program?  Anyways, I am out for tonight.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your program to pass in the path, checked return values of the functions you call and implemented the suggestion offered up by @MarkPlotnick which is the root cause of your trouble:

```
#include <limits.h>

void ls_l(const char *path){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat fileStat;

    dir = opendir(path);
    if(!dir) {
        printf("opendir failed\n");
        return;
    }
    while (((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)){
        char path2[PATH_MAX];
        // if path contains a trailing /, you will end up with //
        // in path2 which is ugly but works fine.  You could special case that,
        // and also special case ./ not being copied into path2
        snprintf(path2, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", path, file->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", path2);

        if(lstat(path2, &fileStat)) {
            printf("lstat failed\n");
            return;
        }
     ...
```

As for step 2, it works for me, so you just need to ensure that `file6.txt` is in the `dir0/` directory.

Comment: Update your question with your current code.  Also include the output from `pwd; ls -l` from the relevant directory.  It works for me, so ether you didn't make those changes correctly or you are looking at the wrong path.

Comment: Your code helped me greatly, in that now I am getting error messages back if there were any errors in the path. However, the comparisons are still sending back incorrect values. When confirming the permissions of the directories for example (using ls -l), I get back permission rwx--x--x, but the code gives back rwxrwxrwx.

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: Instead of `sprintf+lstat` use  `fstatat(dirfd(dir), file->d_name, ...`